# How to send/pass jquery datatable to the controller

Tags: jquery, .net, model-view-controller

In My view I have a Jquery datatable like:

```
$("#contenttable").DataTable({
                    responsive: true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/PlaylistManagement/mthd_getPlaylistContent",       // Method to call.
                        "type": "GET",                                              // Request type.
                        "datatype": "json"                                          // Datatype of data transfers.
                    },
                    "columnDefs": [{
                        "targets": [2],
                        "visible": false
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": [3],
                        "visible": false
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": [4],
                        "visible": false
                    }],
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "playlist_media_sequence_number" },
                        { "data": "playlist_media_name" },
                        { "data": "playlist_media_extension" },
                        { "data": "playlist_media_path" },
                        { "data": "playlist_media_full_path" },
                        {
                            "data": "playlist_media_user_specified_duration", render: function (data, type, row) {
                                return "<input class='form-control'value='" + row.playlist_media_user_specified_duration + "' >";
                            },
                            "orderable": false,
                            "searchable": false,
                            "width": "auto"
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

This datatable consist of the rows which have been selected by the user. this is working fine. but The question is, when the user clicks on the save button,All data should be passed to the controler. how can I do this ? I want to send whole table to the controller method.
and in which format(datatype) I should accept it in the controller and use it ?

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500969/jquery-datatable-data-to-mvc-controller

Comment: My datatable has an input column, so how can I send the data from those input fields

Comment: @Dani Thanks for your help! from your reference you have given, got the solution! thanks again

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :D